# import quandl data inquiry

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, quandl

Sorry noobie here, is there a reason why the row shown is only limited to 5? Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = pd.DataFrame(quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA'))
print(df.head())
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't related to Quandl, it's just that you printed only the head of the data frame. Were you intending to do something else instead?

Comment: hey Camille thanks for your reply!  im just exploring on extraction of financial data from Quandl (sorry very new on this!) . would you recommend the premium data package?

Comment: I have no idea, but the issue of printing only 5 rows is that you called `.head()`, which is to print on the top few rows. That would be the same regardless of the source of your data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default `head()` method shows top 5 rows so if you want to see more rows,then pass the number of rows in `n` parameter of `head()` method

i.e

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = pd.DataFrame(quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA')) 
print(df.head(n=10))
```

now it will show you top 10 rows